# Error to integrate the citrus payment

Tags: citrus-pay

I integrated the Citrus payment code in PHP. I received the error like

> Access is denied
>
> Bad Request:Following parameters are missing-Return URL

Comment: Hi, would you mind sharing the relevant code snippets of your issue, in order to improve the clarity of your question.